# Trying to do a vlookup where the lookup value changes

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test
    Dim LR as Long
    LR = Range(“B” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Range(“E11:E” & LR).Formula = “=Vlookup(B11,’[Ckrun.txt]Ckrun’!$A$2:$E” & LR & “,5,False)”
End sub
```

In my workbook, the formula could start at E12, E13, depending on the data in the file. Also, the formula could reference B12 or B13, depending on the data. How to I get my formula to be able to change from week to week?

Comment: You could use R1C1 format: `.FormulaR1C1 = "=Vlookup(RC2,'[Ckrun.txt]Ckrun'!C1:C5,5,False)"`

Comment: How do I make it where the formula is entered into E11 but change it to be variable?

Comment: Just change the `Range("...")` bit to use whatever range you want.

Comment: How do you know which row the formula starts in?

Comment: Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,1).select is where the lookup value will always be so the formula starts in .Offset(1,4)